# Rotation matrix function for skeletal action recognition

Tags: geometry

I have a set of $25$ points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ giving the joints of a human. What I want to do is write code following this description:

> "We translate them [the joints] to the body coordinate system with its origin on
> the “middle of the spine” joint, followed
> by a rotation to fix the $X$ axis parallel to the vector from
> “right shoulder” to “left shoulder”, and $Y$ axis towards the vector
> from “spine base” to “spine”. The $Z$ axis is fixed as the new $X \times Y$".

Supposing I have a function Rodrigues($v_1$, $v_2$) that gives me the rotation matrix from $v_1$ to $v_2$ (assume that it normalizes both vectors), using Rodrigues formula, i.e. in pseudo-code:

```
M = Rodrigues(v1,v2)

vec_t = M (v1) # vec_t should be roughly equal to v2
```

Now I am trying to figure out the correct sequence of operations to execute the description above. Suppose the joints variable is a matrix of size $(25, 3)$ ($25$ joints, $3$ coordinates $(x,y,z)$). Then my current attempt, assuming the joints have already been translated to the origin at spine base, is something like (in pseudo-code again):

```
def align_joints(joints):
     left_shoulder_index, right_shoulder_index = 4, 8
     spine_base_index, spine_mid_index = 20, 0 
     new_x_axis = joints[left_shoulder]-joints[right_shoulder]
     M1 = Rodrigues([1,0,0], new_x_axis)
     joints = M1.matmul(joints.T).T  # matmul=matrix multiplication, T is transpose
     
     new_y_axis = joints[spine_base_index]-joints[spine_mid_index]
     M2 = Rodrigues([0, 1, 0], new_y_axis)
     joints = M2.matmul(joints.T).T

     new_z_axis = cross_product(M2.matmul(new_x_axis), new_y_axis) 
     M3 = Rodrigues([0, 0, 1], new_z_axis)
     joints = M3.matmul(joints.T).T
```

For whatever reason when I execute these operations and visualize the result, my joints do not look right, so I am wondering if there is any error in the above logic. Any insights appreciated.

Edit:
In python, my Rodrigues function looks like:

```
import numpy as np
# assuming the vec1, vec2 are of shape (3,)
def Rodrigues(vec1, vec2):
    a, b = (vec1 / np.linalg.norm(vec1)).reshape(3), (vec2 / 
        np.linalg.norm(vec2)).reshape(3)
    v = np.cross(a, b)
    c = np.dot(a, b)
    s = np.linalg.norm(v)
    kmat = np.array([[0, -v[2], v[1]], [v[2], 0, -v[0]], [-v[1], 
        v[0], 0]])
    rotation_matrix = np.eye(3) + kmat + kmat.dot(kmat) * ((1 - c) 
        /(s ** 2))
return rotation_matrix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt using `scipy`, since I don't have access to your `Rodrigues` function to verify its accuracy. Please post sample data when you have a chance.

```
import scipy.spatial
import numpy as np

A = np.eye(3) #original frame
B = np.array([joints[left_shoulder]-joints[right_shoulder],
    joints[spine_base_index]-joints[spine_mid_index],
    cross_product(joints[left_shoulder]-joints[right_shoulder],
        joints[spine_base_index]-joints[spine_mid_index])])
R = scipy.spatial.transform.align_vectors(A,B)
#translate so that midpoint of spine is (0,0,0)
translation = joints[spine_mid_index]
new_points = [R.apply(joint) - translation for joint in joints]
```

Comment: Also the new x axis is normalized anyway in the Rodrigues function. I'm not sure what you mean "about the scaling". I wrote the Rodrigues function myself, but sure there is one with opencv asa well I believe.

Comment: The origin is the middle of the spine after translation, and originally is the pinhole of the depth camera.

Comment: I should add that the shoulder and spine vectors won't necessarily be orthogonal, will that matter?

Comment: @IntegrateThis. In general it does matter, but the method I've provided assumes the fit is noisy, so approximate orthogonality is OK